# How to fill empty column values with another dataframe's value if two other columns have matching values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two similar dataframes. I want to populate `df2['Material']` with the value from `df1['Material']` if `df1['PartNumber']` and `df2['PartNumber']` match. Do can I accomplish this with Pandas (or Python in general)? The data frames are several thousand lines each, these are just snippets.

```
df1
    PartNumber      Material    ProgramNo   Machine

114 JEFD0302000 E   304L        O0219       CHNC III
218 REFD0502050 B   6AL-4V      O0295       CHNC III

df2
    PartNumber      ProgramNo     Machine   Material

0   JEFD0302670 A   6109 + 6609   WY-100    NaN
1   JEFD0510820 A   6110 + 6610   WY-100    NaN
```

Comment: Yes you can. Please check documentation for the dataframe join (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) method

Comment: I do not want to join the dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do :

```
df2['Material']=df2['PartNumber'].map(dict(zip(df1['PartNumber'],df1['Material']))).fillna(df2.Material)
```

Comment: @55thSwiss Pleasure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where` with `map`

```
s=df2.PartNumber.map(df1.set_index('PartNumber').Material)    
df2.Material=np.where(df2.PartNumber.isnull(),s,df2.Material)
```

Comment: this produces `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` once you add the missing `)` in line 1

Comment: @55thSwiss ok fixed